# Determine sampling interval for each unique value, from timestamps in HIVE table

Tags: sql, datetime, count, hiveql, window-functions

I have a HIVE table:

```
device           timestamp            value
  d_1        2020-08-15 00:05:00       10
  d_1        2020-08-15 00:10:00       12
  d_1        2020-08-15 00:15:00       08
  d_2        2020-08-15 00:05:00       62
  d_2        2020-08-15 00:25:00       14
  d_2        2020-08-15 00:45:00       10
```

Notice how device d_1 has a different time interval (5 seconds) than device d_2 (20 seconds).

For a large table with millions of rows, how can I determine the sampling interval for all the unique devices?

I am looking for output like this:

```
 device       sampling_interval(mins)   
  d_1                  5
  d_2                 20
```

Comment: What if the sampling interval is not constant, say a device has some missing data points, or its interval changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest possible approach would be to use `lag()` to compute the duration of each and every interval between consecutive data points of the same device, and then count how many times each interval occurred:

```
select
    device,
    (unix_timestamp(ts) - unix_timestamp(lag_ts)) / 60 sampling_interval_minutes,
    count(*) no_hits
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(ts) over(partition by device order by ts) lag_ts
    from mytable t
) t
group by device, (unix_timestamp(ts) - unix_timestamp(lag_ts)) / 60 
order by device, no_hits desc
```

This makes it easy to check the consistency of intervals, and see which one occurs the most.

Comment: I am getting parse errors from this query. Not sure how to resolve. It says there are missing closing parentheses near EOF

Comment: @Cybernetic: fixed

Comment: Just to be sure, no_hits is number of hits, not "no hits"

Comment: @Cybernetic: yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you. Your query looks great, I just can't explain the # hits I'm getting with a time interval of 0. I do get the right number of hits for the expected non-zero time intervals (e.g. 5 mins) but I also get millions of rows with a time interval of 0. Why would so many 0s be there for # hits? These are 27 day chunks of time that keep repeating.

Comment: @Cybernetic: basically it means that you have data points that are less than 1 minutes one from the other. You might want to remove the division by 60 from the query so you get the exact interval duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the average difference using:

```
select device,
       (unix_timestamp(max(timestamp)) - unix_timestamp(min(timestamp))) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from t
group by device;
```

This gives the average difference in timestamps between rows.

Comment: I am getting wrong values. For devices I know have 5 minute sampling intervals I am getting ~0.2. This happens to be the sampling frequency (not interval) but I don't think that's what this is calculating either.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using unixtimestamp? I don't think my dates work with unixtimestamp.

Comment: This gives the average difference in seconds per device.  `unix_timestamp()` should work on a reasonably formatted data value.